# Show Discord bot as online

Tags: discord

I'm working on a custom Discord bot using their [api](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference). Sending HTTP requests work but the bot doesn't actually show itself as online.

Other bots such as Dynobot are able to show themselves as online, am I missing something or is it just a case of how many requests are sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, are you working directly with the API, as in sending HTTP requests?

If so...there really is no need to do this. Instead, **use a library to code your Discord bot.** [Here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/community-resources#libraries) is a list of official libraries for the Discord API. Personally I recommend Discord.js, although I have heard that Discord.py and Discord.NET are also good.

If you want to keep using the API directly, which I do not recommend at all, I believe you can call `/api/login`. Have you tried that yet?

I hope this helped! :)

Comment: I ended up moving everything over to a library since it makes life easier. I'll mark this as the solution.